# macbookpro/wireless vlc/qt to a projector

Tags: wifi, audio, video, projector

Airfoil, connects nicely to my speakers and the 3 macs + pads/phones in the studio connect nicely to it but what about wirelessly sharing the projector?

is there anything (NOT an apple tv) which can connect my projector (has only hdmi/vga/composite) to the rest of the network?

Perhaps a dongle, or wireless thing I can plug in to it?
I really dont want an apple tv, just some hardware w. software which i can install to project from any device wirelessly.

Seems simple but I cant find anything ?

Surely there's an answer? Google's not giving me much.

Comment: Is your projector WiFi capable ? What projector ?

Comment: nope its a 'dumb projector', plug something witha signal in an it will work

Comment: Does your Projector has a USB plug ?

Comment: Take look at the WUSB (wireless USB to USB connection, that is not WiFi) set up, if your projector has a USB plug.

Comment: no usb sadly. :-(